# AngularJS Custom Directive callback not being called

Tags: angularjs

I basically created a custom directive that updates an ngModel attribute and calls a callback.

The callback however is not being called. I think it's because the directive is using an isolated scope?

http://jsfiddle.net/KzMvR/9/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="row in data">
    {{row.name}} {{row.email}}
    <button load load-callback="callback(row);"
            ng-model="row">Load</button>
  </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('load', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
  return {
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var callback = $parse(attrs.loadCallback);

      element.bind("click", function () {
        scope.ngModel = {
          name: 'martin',
          email: 'martin@test.com'
        };
        callback(scope);  // calls callback
      });
    }
  }
}]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
    {
      name: 'john',
      email: 'john@doe.com'
    },
    {
      name: 'ben',
      email: 'ben@test.com'
    }
  ];

  $scope.callback = function (data) {
    console.log(data + ' from callback1');
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to pass the callback function using `&` notation and call using `callback({data:scope})`.

See the updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/qLELn/

**Questions** : 
Why are you not using `ng-click` and doing custom binding on click event.

Why pass the complete scope?

Update: Based on your feedback here is the updated fiddle that updates the model too

http://jsfiddle.net/qLELn/2/

Comment: hi chandermani, the directive is actually more complex than i presented. on click, it will return an object. that's why if you noticed, the ngmodel is updated within the click event..

Comment: in your fiddle, the ngmodel, however is not anymore updated.. basically, the ngmodel should be updated and the callback will be called. the callback will be called on the original scope so that it will get whatever the updated value of the ngmodel is

Comment: When you say ngModel is not updated what do you mean?

Comment: in the click event, the ngmodel is being updated. however, in the callback it's not being updated